# Find the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt[5]{x^3-\tan^3x}$ in $x=0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the function:

$$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{3cm} f(x) = \sqrt[5]{x^3-\tan^3x} $$

I have to find $f'(0)$.

I first found the derivative:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{5\sqrt[5]{(x^3-\tan^3x)^4}} \cdot \bigg( 3x^2 - \dfrac{3 \tan^2x}{\cos^2x} \bigg )$$

And I can't find this at $x=0$ since the first term of the product would be $\dfrac{1}{0}$.

Comment: Apply definition of derivative and use Taylor expansion of $\tan x$around $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the definition of derivative,
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x^3-\tan^3(x)}}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt[5]{\frac{(x-\tan(x))\left(x^2+x\tan(x)+\tan^2(x)\right)}{x^5}}$$
You can then compute
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\tan(x)}{x^3}=-\frac 13 $$
using L'Hospital's rule or series expansion, and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+x\tan(x)+\tan^2(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+\frac{\tan(x)}{x}+\frac{\tan^2(x)}{x^2}\right)=3 $$
since $\lim_{x\to 0}\tan(x)/x=1$. So $f'(0)=\sqrt[5]{-\frac 13\cdot 3}=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You could get many derivatives composing Taylor series
$$f(x)=\sqrt[5]{x^3-\tan^3(x)}$$
Using the expansion of $\tan(x)$, we then have
$$x^3-\tan^3(x)=-x^5-\frac{11 x^7}{15}-\frac{88 x^9}{189}-\frac{1282 x^{11}}{4725}-\frac{133
   x^{13}}{891}+O\left(x^{15}\right)$$ that is to say
$$x^3-\tan^3(x)=-x^5\left(1+\frac{11 x^2}{15}+\frac{88 x^4}{189}+\frac{1282 x^6}{4725}+\frac{133  x^8}{891}+O\left(x^{10}\right) \right)$$ Now, using the binomial theorem
$$f(x)=-x\left(1+\frac{11 x^2}{75}+\frac{5918 x^4}{118125}+\frac{164456
   x^6}{8859375}+\frac{1076727314 x^8}{153488671875}+O\left(x^{10}\right) \right)$$